# Conditionally apply login_required decorator in Django

Tags: python, django, decorator

I have a set of function in `views.py` which are currently only user-accessible. I'm asked to make it publicly accessible and currently I am using the `@login_required` decorator in my views. Is there a way to apply this decorator conditionally based on the object being served?

For example, part of my `views.py`:

```
@login_required
def details(request, object_id):
    o = get_object_or_404(Model, pk=object_id)

    if o.user_id == request.user.pk:
        return render(request, 'app/details.html')
    else:
        return redirect('app:home')
```

What I want to do:

```
if not o.is_public:
    @login_required
def details(request, object_id):
    o = get_object_or_404(Model, pk=object_id)

    if o.user_id == request.user.pk:
        return render(request, 'app/details.html')
    else:
        return redirect('app:home')
```

Of course, the code doesn't work since (i) it's not valid Python and (ii) I need to first get the object. I believe there might be an elegant solution using Django as this is quite a common feature in web applications but I've gone through the docs to no avail. I think I should surround the `@login_required` decorator with another decorator but I'm not too familiar with decorators in Python. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You would probably need to rewrite login_required decorator. It needs to accept not only function but also another external parameter (o.is_public in this case). And if o.is_public is True then proceed with login validation, otherwise pass.

Comment: @Alasdair You're right, I must've mistyped, will correct that. I meant it to be `if not o.is_public`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `user_passes_test` for this kind of behaviour.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def public_check(user):
    if user.is_public:
        return True

@user_passes_test(public_check)
```

Comment: Good try, but it's not the user that should be public, it's the object. Is there a generic decorator for objects?

Comment: Okay then how about the Model object is relation with `User` in this case you can easily check with reverse relationship like `user.o` ??

Comment: It seems like I'll have to rewrite the decorator for that according to the docs.

Comment: Is your model is relation with `User` table ? then the decorator is fairly easy one to write

Comment: It is indeed. User has many Model objects, any ideas on how to do this? I'm not too familiar with the whole decorator thing

Comment: Okay open python manage.py shell and import User and get the first object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139239/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-syafiq-kamarul-azman).

Answer (score 0):

It will not work with a decorator because decorators are evaluated and applied on import time and, as you've said, you need to get the object first, which is based on the request.

Since you've asked for an elegant solution, and I'm assuming you want to create a decorator for it so you can reuse it on multiple views, then the solution is a class-based view.  You can implement the behavior that you want as a class-based view mixin, which you can mix-in to different class-based views.  This improved flexibility is one of the reasons class-based views were introduced.